# Is there a built-in feature to validate some JAX-RS variable context?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jax-rs, java-ee-6

I am using one class that handles `@Path( "/{site}/group" )` and another one that handles `@Path( "/{site}/user" )`. I have one exception handler for the invalid `{site}` object in the context that returns status `404`, but in order to validate the `{site}` I need to repeat the code on every method I use it. I am getting the `site` from the database and checking if comes `null` (then the exception is thrown).

Is there any built-in feature in JAX-RS that could help me to test the `{site}` context before the methods execution, then I could make some DRY out of this mess? If not what would be the best approach in this case?

EDIT:
(non functional snipped expressing my problem)

Using `@Path( "/{site}/user" )` at class level

Then a method:

```
@GET
public void getUser( String site ) throws ... {
  Site site = findSiteFromDatabase( site );
  if ( site == null ) throw new InvalidException( "Invalid site" );

  ...
}
```

The problem with that approach is that I would have to test for the object validity in every method I create.
It would be very handy an utility that allows me to load the context object once (consider multiple classes using the same approach).

EDIT 2:

My root resource is an EJB, I need this to load the `Site` object from database (using JPA and stuff)

I used an EJB interceptor. The problem with this approach is that I have to always create a method with the fixed arguments `@PathParam( "site" ) String site` and `Site site` (the second argument is for not consulting the database twice).

```
    @AroundInvoke
    public Object initSite( InvocationContext context ) throws Exception {
        String siteName = context.getParameters()[ 0 ].toString();
        SiteEntity siteEntity = siteDAO.findSiteByPath( siteName );
        if ( siteEntity == null ) {
            throw new APINotFoundException( "The site you are accessing does not exist" );
        }

        Object[] params = new Object[]{ siteName, siteEntity };
        context.setParameters( params );

        return context.proceed();
    }

    @GET
    @Path( "/user" )
    public UserData getUser(
        @PathParam( "site" ) String site,
        SiteEntity site
    ) {
        return ...
    }
```

Any approach not requiring me to build a fixed signature is welcome.

EDIT 3:
My solution above did not worked. The EJB interceptor is not able to honor my `ExceptionMapper` declaration (It always returns status 500). I am almost giving up, did anyone got into the same problem?

Comment: Have you looked at the Validation API?

Comment: No I haven't, did you mean Bean Validation?

Comment: Yes, JSR-303 (now 349). In particular, it seems that `@NotNull` might do what you want, depending on how your container will apply the validation constraints (e.g., can you validate method parameters?).

Comment: I do not want to validate the parameter itself, I want to validate the object I get from the database using the `{site}` parameter. I may do that for every method I create, but that would imply lots of code repetition.

Comment: I edited the question, hope it is more clear.

Comment: Is your resource class an EJB? In that case you can use [interceptors](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkedm.html). Otherwise JAX-RS provides a [similar concept](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html).

Comment: Yes, my resource class is an EJB

Comment: I used EJB interceptors and `@AroundInvoke` annotation in a `initSite` method. The problem with this approach is that I have to always create a method with the arguments `@PathParam( "site" ) String site` and `Site site` (I don't want to consult the database twice so I pass the instance as parameter from the interceptor). Any approach not requiring me to build a proper signature is welcome.

Comment: I edited the question to make it clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far I know, there isn't no such a default behavior in JEE. This is how I would solve this issue.

1. Adapt your restful endpoint URL(s) to: ***(You will need this since the usage of regular exprssion for the `<url-pattern>` tags is very limmited!)***

   `@Path( "/user/{site}")`

   `@Path( "/group/{site}")`
2. Create a User and a Group request filter sth. like: ***(Just pseudo source!!!)***

   ```
   public class UserFilter implements Filter { 
   @Override
   public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

   }

   @Override
   public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
           FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

       HttpServletRequest req = null;
       boolean valid = false;
       PrintWriter out = null;

       if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {

           req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
           // TODO extract site info from url ...
           // TODO perform check ...
           // valid = ...
       }

       if (valid) {
           chain.doFilter(request, response);
       } else {

           response.setContentType("text/html");
           out = response.getWriter();
           out.println("<html><head><title>Your specific response</title></head><body>");
           out.println("<h2>Sorry, Unknown URL!</h2>");

           out.println("</body></html>");
           out.close();
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void destroy() {

   }
   ```

   }
3. Add your filter in web.xml:

   ```
   <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
       version="2.5">
       ...
       <filter>
           <filter-name>User validation fiter</filter-name>
           <filter-class>path.to.your.UserFilter</filter-class>
       </filter>
       <filter-mapping>
           <filter-name>User validation fiter</filter-name>
           <url-pattern>/services/user/*</url-pattern>
       </filter-mapping>

       <filter>
           <filter-name>Group validation fiter</filter-name>
           <filter-class>path.to.your.GroupFilter</filter-class>
       </filter>
       <filter-mapping>
           <filter-name>Group validation fiter</filter-name>
           <url-pattern>/services/group/*</url-pattern>
       </filter-mapping>
       ...
   </web-app>
   ```

Comment: Very good approach, but the API URL should be as specified and I can't have much control due to the `url-mapping limitations`. To have more control I should implement some filter to take care of the `url-mapping`, but that would imply too much classes and dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I can see tow option:

[BeanParm](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html)  (need JAX-RS 2.0, possible to upgrade JAX-RS in JBoss 7):

```
public SiteBean{

   @PathParam
   private String site;

   public Site getSite() throws WebApplicationException{
       Site s = findSiteFromDatabase( site );
       if ( s == null ) throw new WebApplicationExcepiton();
       // you can customize the Responce in the WebApplicationException
   }
}
```

In every method requesting the site you need to do:

```
@GET
public void getUser( @BeanParam SiteBean site ){
      Site s = site.getSite();
}
```

Other option is to use [sub-resources](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2082).

```
@Path("{site}")
public SiteResource{

    private Site site;

    public SiteResource(@PathParam String site) throws new WebApplicationExcepiton{
         this.site = = findSiteFromDatabase( site );
         if ( s == null ) throw new WebApplicationExcepiton();
       // you can customize the Responce in the WebApplicationException
    }

    @Path("user")
    public UserResource user(){
         return new UserResource(site);
    }

    ... // same for other sub resource.
}
```

The User resource:

```
public UserResource{
    private Site site;

    public UserResource(Site site){
        this.site = site;
    }

    @GET
    public void getUser{
       ...
    }

    ...
}
```

The last one should work with JAX-RS 1.1.

Comment: The first alternative is amazing! Sadly it does not work in Java EE 6 (like you  mentioned). How would I use that in a JBoss version that supports Java EE 6? Is there any problems using one upgraded API?

The second approach I think is the way to go, that is, assuming the constructor actually is executed every time I access the `{site}` context.

Comment: Unfortunately your second approach did not worked. I am using the root resource as EJB, in order to make that work I need to declare a constructor with empty arguments, so I suppose the container is invoking the no-arguments constructor instead of the desired one (to test for the site existence). Since the "findSiteFromDatabase" method comes from another EJB injected in the same class, I fail to make it work. Any suggestions? =/

Comment: I used EJB interceptors and `@AroundInvoke` annotation in a `initSite` method. The problem with this approach is that I have to always create a method with the arguments `@PathParam( "site" ) String site` and `Site site` (I don't want to consult the database twice so I pass the instance as parameter from the interceptor). Any approach not requiring me to build a proper signature is welcome.

Comment: You can easyly upgrade Resteasy (JAX-RS implementation) in Jboss AS7 (and EAP 6.x) [Resteasy upgrade](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.6.Final/userguide)/html/Installation_Configuration.html#upgrading-as7

Comment: For option 2 you will probably need to change a bit the structure.

Comment: Resteasy documentation show another option [making Site class as JAX-RS resource](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.6.Final/userguide/html/JAX-RS_Resource_Locators_and_Sub_Resources.html)
You can also create a CDI `@request` scoped `Site` wrapper and instead of a object you can return the class of the resource (in the resdource locator method) in which you inject the `Site` wrapper.  You will need to test if it works with `EJB`.  CDI never letme down to get correct solution to my issues ;).

Answer (score 0):

Why not throwing an exception from your `findSiteFromDatabase( site )` method instead of returning a `null` value ? (btw, JPA has a similar behaviour with `Query#getSingleResult()` : http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getSingleResult%28%29 ).

Then, you could use an JAX-RS ExceptionMapper to convert the exception into a JSON/XML/HTML response with the proper return code and body, depending on your needs.

Comment: But that would imply that I need to call the method every time I want to access some resource inside the `{site}` context. The use case is the following: I have a `{site}` path, any method inside that path should NOT be accessible and provide a 404 if the site does not exist in the database. I can't just remember to call some method every time I want to check if the site exists. Is that use case so crazy?

Comment: It is like `{user}/info` but `/info` should not execute if `{user}` does not exist (and send a custom 404 instead)

Comment: oh, I see ! Then why not using a JAX-RS 2 Filter bound to the methods you need to check ? Or an implementation-specific Filter/Interceptor ?

Comment: * I can't use JAX RS 2 because I use Java EE 6. * I can't use EJB interceptors because they do not handle the exceptions with ExceptionMapper. * I may use a servlet filter, but I was wondering if I could somehow do something with JAX RS itself.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking about Jersey filters (https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.1.5/user-guide.html#d4e681) or RESTEasy filters (http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.7.Final/userguide/html/Interceptors.html#PreProcessInterceptors), depending on the platform on which you plan to deploy your application.

Comment: I am looking for portability though